# How current is GDAL in Java

Tags: gdal, ogr, java, ogr2ogr

I have used ogr2ogr to import various formats to PostgreSQL and have used GDAL utilities. Is there a complete Java port for these tools or are they simply wrappers calling JNI to C++ code?

I have seen some Java stuff by Googling but not sure how much are they current and kept up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the GDAL site, the project has SWIG generated [Java bindings](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInJava) for GDAL and OGR. They have instructions for building build the Java bindings from scratch in [Windows](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInJavaBuildInstructions) and [Unix](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInJavaBuildInstructionsUnix). The site also has a [Javadoc](http://gdal.org/java/) for the API which applies to GDAL version 1.7.0 and higher.

Comment: This seems to be a wrapper to C++. Is there an all Java implementation of GDAL and OGR?

Comment: That's what SWIG generated bindings mean. As far as I know, there isn't one.