# How to reproduce the gdal utility programs in Java by GDAL Java bindings

Tags: gdal, java, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

Can anyone tell me how can I reproduce the gdal utility programs gdal_translate, gdalwarp and gdal2tiles in java by GDAL Java bindings?

Comment: Have you considered the GDAL Java bindings? http://gdal.org/java/

Comment: See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34600/how-current-is-gdal-in-java

Comment: Yes I considered GDAL Java bindings but I can't find any explanation about how to implement the gdal_translate in Java by GDAL Java bindings

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you edited some of that background into your question then I think it more likely that people would vote to re-open it.

Comment: Examples are here: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/java/apps/