# Create shapefile from data postgis / kml using java

Tags: postgis, postgresql, java

I'm working on a geographic information system project, whose products form shapefile. I am using java language, and PostGIS database. Is there a way to generate a shp file from PostGIS or kml using java language?

Comment: The easiest way to do it with any language is running the appropiate tool.

Comment: is there any example or tutorial or reference?

Comment: Maybe this Q/A may help, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34600/how-current-is-gdal-in-java

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate, but there are no Java solutions in the question it was marked as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at GeoTools http://geotools.org/.  It is the one open source GIS package in Java that I know of.